# Remove title bar from post-new.php

Tags: title

I want to remove post title bar form the admin area. So that the users can't add title. Users will be able to add description only.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any particular user role you are looking, to apply this functionality.I think this is the irrelevant question but anyway can you give some clarity ?

Comment: Are you using the Block Editor or the Classic Editor? Each of them would have a far different method.